# Why won't AR allow me to make an attribute setter private using `private :accepted=`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've just setup a new boolean `accepted` attribute on my model that looks like this:

```
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_protected :accepted
  ...

end
```

I want it to be a private attribute however when I attempt to remove the public setter like this:

```
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_protected :accepted
  private :accepted=
  ...

end
```

I get an immediate failure of the type:

```
invitation.rb:17:in `private': undefined method `accepted=' for class `Invitation' (NameError)
```

Why isn't AR detecting the setter? I do know that I could do this by defining the method in longhand but I am interested as to why I can't use the shorthand `private :accepted=` route.

Comment: May I know, why do you want to do that?

Comment: I want an accept_and_save() method and to keep the actual attribute private.

Comment: Cool, you may then try re-defining the setter method by yourself, giving it private scope.

Comment: That's the way I've ultimately ended up going. It's not quite as tight  as I'd like but it gets the job done - cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute getters and setters are not actual methods, they are implemented using `method_missing` in ActiveRecord. That's why you can't manipulate them using `private`.

Comment: You can however manipulate the getters and setters if you've declared an attribute via an association i.e. if I had `invitation has_one owner ` I could declare `private :owner=`. Does this only apply to associations?

Comment: Yea associations are not implemented that way, they have actual methods. It's kind of complicated and if you want to understand all the details I guess you actually have to look through the ActiveRecord code.